# Unable to update libcurl version

Tags: linux, shell, curl, libcurl

I am trying to update libcurl version from 7.79.1 to 8.4.0 on my linux machine

but in the process, while trying to run

```
 wget https://curl.se/download/curl-8.4.0.zip
```

I am getting below error :-

```
 --2023-10-17 14:34:14--  https://curl.se/download/curl-8.4.0.zip
Resolving curl.se (curl.se)... 151.101.193.91, 151.101.1.91, 151.101.65.91, ...
Connecting to curl.se (curl.se)|151.101.193.91|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Why does that error contain `https://www.somedownload.com/`? How is this problem related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase i pasted the wrong error, just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your wget version, or download with this command :

```
curl -k -O https://curl.se/download/curl-8.4.0.zip
```

Comment: i m getting this error :  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to curl.se:443